# Lenovo W510 startup issue

Tags: boot, bios, thinkpad

I was searching for a BIOS update for my Thinkpad W510 and found that there is a new update for it on the Lenovo website.

I downloaded a BIOS update for my Thinkpad W510 from Lenovo's website and installed it. As normal, it asked me to restart the computer.
I clicked restart but it didn't switch off and I couldn't even turn it off with the power button.
When I pressed the power button, I heard 1 long beep and 3 short beeps while the computer stayed on.

I took the battery out and put it back in to restart my PC.  But now, when I press the power button, it does nothing anymore. I see that the light around the power button is on but the screen doesn't go on anymore. It doesn't beep or anything: it just does nothing except turn the lights and fan on.

Yes, I tried holding the power button for 60 seconds after I took the adapter and battery off. And no, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Thinkpad troubleshooting guide](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht035729). It doesn't mention the beep code you've heard. 1 long beep, 2 short beeps is the closest one and it indicates motherboard, RAM or LCD problem.

Basically, flashing went wrong and contacting Lenovo is your best bet. There's not much you can do yourself other than things you have already tried.